# Is there a way to create a collection, commit to review set, and create + download a Purview case export via API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-purview

Title says it all I think.

I'm trying to do end to end Purview collection and export via the API. I can create a case, add a data source, but still need to create a collection, commit to review set, create and download an export of all documents in that review set.

Are these latter steps possible via the API?  I'm struggling to find documentation on them.

Comment: Might you have explored using the ediscovery beta Graph APIs? You can use Create sourceCollection API to create a collection: POST /compliance/ediscovery/cases/{caseId}/sourceCollections. Then adding the collection to a reviewSet using the addToReviewSet : POST /compliance/ediscovery/cases/{caseId}/reviewSets/{reviewsetId}/addToReviewSet. Then export via the reviewSet export API: POST /compliance/ediscovery/cases/{caseId}/reviewsets/{reviewsetId}/export

Comment: Find the documentation for those APIs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/ediscovery-ediscoveryapioverview?view=graph-rest-beta